# php get US/Eastern current time

Tags: php

I want to get current time of US/Eastern timezone. How would I achieve that.

I have tried following code but it is displaying my system's time.

```
<?php
   date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
   $currenttime = date('h:i:s:u');
   list($hrs,$mins,$secs,$msecs) = split(':',$currenttime);
   //print "&time2=".$secs."&time1=".$mins."&time0=".$hrs;
?>
```

I am using this script with flash so commented out 'print' line.

Comment: Can you try calling `echo date_default_timezone_get()`, and see what it echoes?

Comment: Please be aware that 'US/Eastern', while deprecated, follows 'Daylight Saving Time' rules. It is either GMT-04:00 or GMT-05:00 depending on the time of year. If you want specifically EDT(Eastern Daylight Time, summer) OR EST(Eastern Standard Time, Winter), you will need to specify the 3-character acronym or the offset directly.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
<?php
   echo date_default_timezone_get();
   $currenttime = date('h:i:s:u');
   list($hrs,$mins,$secs,$msecs) = split(':',$currenttime);
   echo " => $hrs:$mins:$secs\n";

   date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
   echo date_default_timezone_get();
   $currenttime = date('h:i:s:u');
   list($hrs,$mins,$secs,$msecs) = split(':',$currenttime);
   echo " => $hrs:$mins:$secs\n";

   date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
   echo date_default_timezone_get();
   $currenttime = date('h:i:s:u');
   list($hrs,$mins,$secs,$msecs) = split(':',$currenttime);
   echo " => $hrs:$mins:$secs\n";

?>
```

Seems to work here (in Berlin):

```
Europe/Berlin => 01:42:42
US/Eastern => 07:45:18
America/New_York => 07:45:18
```

Comment: i had one mistake that was creating the confusion, i had to use 'H' instead of 'h' in date format. Sorry guyz... and thanks too... especially The MYYN whose date_default_timezone_get() suggestion helped me...

Comment: Deprecated: Function split()

Comment: This code is giving me an error

Answer (score 20):

```
$amNY = new DateTime('America/New_York');
$estTime = $amNY->format('h:i:s:u');
```

or if you are using php **5.4 and above**

```
estTime = (new DateTime('America/New_York'))->format('h:i:s:u');
```

`date_default_timezone_set()` will affect the **whole script** and should be used carefully

Comment: This works for me, while miku's answer above did not.

Answer (score 8):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Looks like the `US/Eastern` is deprecated. Try `America/New_York`

**EDIT** this probably won't fix your problem, but you should do it anyway. Being deprecated means that they could remove it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to use `gmmktime()` to get the `Unix timestamp` for the current GMT, then `subtract 5 hours` from it.  That way you get Eastern Time no matter where the server happens to be.

Comment: And what about when Eastern Standard Time switches to Eastern Daylight Time (-4 GMT)? This isn't really a sustainable fix.

Comment: It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just use

```
<?php
Date_default_timezone('est');
$lv=date('l, F jS, Y, g:I:s A T,$ir['laston']);
?>
<b>last visit</b> <em>$lv.</em>
```

Seems to work perfectly for me on my game that I'm working on. Mind you if you want to use it just remove the $ir['laston'] and it should work no problem

Comment: But this function doesn't actually exist.

Comment: The function is lower case.